# why no set/getHeader in Symfony2's Request and Response class

Tags: symfony

although the headers attribute are public.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because they are public. Just access them through the property directly:

```
$request->headers->get('Content-Type');
```

The request header collection is an instance of `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\HeaderBag`, the response headers are contained in a `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag`.